# Console.log not showing in second layer of node promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodegit

I'm creating a custom CHANGELOG generator based on git commits using [nodegit](https://www.nodegit.org) (I didn't quite like the existing similar projects, and it's a pretty simple tool to make, in theory at least).

My problem right now is that I can't seem to get the `console.log` to show any output when it's in the second layer of promises.

This code shows the first `console.log` entry, but the second one disappears into cyberspace. It doesn't show any errors or anything, it just doesn't appear in the console.

```
git.Repository.open(repo_root).then(function (repo_handle) {
  repo_handle.Tag.list(repo_handle).then(function (tag_list) {
    console.log("THIS SHOWS"); // <--- Shows
    repo_handle.getTagByName(tag_list[0]).then(function (tag) {
      console.log("THIS DOES NOT"); // <--- Doesn't show
    });
  });
});
```

And just to verify that the problem isn't in the `getTagByName` function, the below code works just fine and outputs `THIS SHOWS`, so it's something related to putting the logging function in the second layer of the promises.

```
git.Repository.open(repo_root).then(function (repo_handle) {
  repo_handle.getTagByName('v0.0.1').then(function (tag) {
    console.log("THIS SHOWS");
  });
});
```

I've tried a couple different versions of the same code by the way, e.g. using `return repo_handle.Tag.list(repo_handle)` and `then(tag_list)`, but the results were the same.

As far as I can tell the code isn't actually having any errors or anything, the code seems to work just fine since I'm not getting any errors, but then again if `console.log` isn't working properly then it could just be the case that it isn't showing me the errors either...

Comment: `then` only fires if your promise is successful, so your promise isn't successful. You don't actually show what `getTagByName` does so beyond that we can't help

Comment: offtopic: nested `.then()` is anti-pattern, they are supposed to be chained, not forming another callback hell

Comment: @Liam getTagByName is part of the `nodegit` API, so if you wanna see it you'd have to head on over there. It's an async function that returns a `Tag` object.

Comment: @William Chong Now that you mention it I know I've read about that before and actually know about it... I'm gonna pretend this was just test code that just needed to work, not be good ^^

Comment: off topic, did you know you surname means "ugly" in welsh? Not to make any comment on your character or person but thought you might find it interesting :)

Comment: @Liam What seriously?? Haha that's random xD

Comment: Yep seriously https://forvo.com/word/hyll/ "ll" is a character in welsh and has an unusual pronunciation, if you press the play icon on that link you'll see what I mean.

Comment: In Swedish "hyll" is 1 letter from "hylla" which means "shelf", so people joke about us being the shelfs, but now I guess we can be the ugly shelfs... And we're Swedish... WE'RE [BILLY THE BOOKCASE](https://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/products/S59182201/) FROM IKEA!! xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably means that `repo_handle.getTagByName('v0.0.1').then(function (tag) {` never starts. Try something like this:

```
git.Repository.open(repo_root).then(function (repo_handle) {
    repo_handle.Tag.list(repo_handle).then(function (tag_list) {
        console.log("THIS SHOWS"); // <--- Shows
        repo_handle.getTagByName(tag_list[0]).then(function (tag) {
            console.log("THIS DOES NOT"); // <--- Doesn't show
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("gotcha! ", error);
        });
    });
});
```

console.log itself has nothing to to with the depth of promise nesting

## Update from asker

For those that find this later, the actual problem turned out to be that `repo_handle.Tag` was undefined, and I found it thanks to adding a `catch` for the error, hence accepting this answer.

The new updated code that works is as follows:

```
let nodegit = require('nodegit');
let path = require('path');

var repo_root = path.resolve(__dirname, './.git');
let repo = null;

nodegit.Repository.open(repo_root)
  .then(function (repo_handle) {
    repo = repo_handle;
    return nodegit.Tag.list(repo_handle);
  })
  .then(function (tag_list) {
    return repo.getTagByName(tag_list[0]);
  })
  .then(function (tag) {
    console.log(tag.message());
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Comment: I feel so stupid for not thinking of using a `.catch` for errors... It turns out there's some problem with `repo_handle.Tag.list` being undefined, even if I swear to Jebus that there are no errors in the code in that part since I used that part like 30 minutes ago fully functional... Will accept your answer since it lead to the solution, thanks!